# SQL: linking two different columns in one

Tags: sql

I need to link 2 tables in one big table. 
My problem is that I need to link 2 different columns (in example: books, toys) in one column (things).
Other columns:

- if they are in both tables, then they are in one column in every row (in example: price)
- if they are in one table, then in rows with data from other table have null (in example: cover, name).

Example:
table 1:

```
books cover price
----- ----- ------
book1 soft  19
book2 soft  23
book3 hard  39
```

table2:

```
toys  name price
----  ---- -----
astro Buzz 29
mouse Jerr 35
```

Result:

```
things name cover price
------ ---- ----- -----
book1  null soft  19
book2  null soft  23
book3  null hard  39
astro  Buzz null  29
mouse  Jerr null  35
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a `UNION ALL` more info [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php)

Something like this:

```
SELECT books "things", NULL "name", cover, price
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT toys "things", name , NULL "cover", price
FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple UNION:

```
select books as things, null as name, cover, price
from table1
union
select toys as things, name, null as cover, price from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Cross Apply like this using your exmaple

```
select * from table1 cross apply table2
```

or you could use the UNION ALL

```
SELECT books as 'THINGS', NULL as 'NAME', COVER, PRICE
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT toys 'THINGS', NAME, NULL 'COVER', PRICE
FROM table2
```

Comment: `cross apply` is non-standard SQL. And in this case it is the same as a `cross join` - which is not what kamil wants actually